# What's the difference between running mysql.server and mysqld

Tags: mysql

I just installed mysql via brew on my mac.

I noticed that you can start the mysql server either ways, `mysql.server start` or `mysqld` on the terminal.

What is the difference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Invoke mysqld directly. This works on any platform.

Invoke mysqld_safe, which tries to determine the proper options for mysqld and then runs it with those options. This script is used on Unix and Unix-like systems. See mysqld_safe — MySQL Server Startup Script.

Invoke mysql.server. This script is used primarily at system startup and shutdown on systems that use System V-style run directories (that is, /etc/init.d and run-level specific directories), where it usually is installed under the name mysql. The mysql.server script starts the server by invoking mysqld_safe. See mysql.server — [[MySQL Server Startup Script](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-server.html).]

On Mac OS X, install a separate MySQL Startup Item package to enable the automatic startup of MySQL on system startup. The Startup Item starts the server by invoking mysql.server. See [Installing MySQL on Mac OS X, for details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/macosx-installation.html).

More Details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-linuxunix-excerpt/5.0/en/automatic-start.html